# How to solve 'str' object has no attribute 'lemma_' using Spacy?

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

I tried to do a lemmatization for my DataFrame using `Spacy` in python. The code that I used is like this below:

```py
# import spaCy's language model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# function to lemmatize text
def lemmatization(texts):
    output = []
    for i in texts:
        lem = [str(token).lemma_ for token in nlp(i) or str(token) in ["-PRON-"]]
        output.append(' '.join(lem))
    return output

train['clean_tweet'] = lemmatization(train['clean_tweet'])
test['clean_tweet'] = lemmatization(test['clean_tweet'])
```

turns out I get an error which said:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'lemma_'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Remove str from your token , token contain lemma attribute and not python str

Comment: Thank you for your answer before, but if I remove str from that it happen to shows "object of type 'float' has no len()" error :(

Comment: dataset that you are using , will have nan value, fill NaN value with empty string , and i have posted a solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string_ = "I am will be playing football tommorrow" # dummy string 
obj = nlp(string_)
lemmatize_token = [x.lemma_ for x in obj]

print(lemmatize_token)
['I', 'be', 'will', 'be', 'play', 'football', 'tommorrow']
```

Comment: Please add some text description to the answer. Only code answers are not considered high quality answers.